# discord.py - channel.connect() not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I´m trying to connect my bot to a voice channel and tried every solution I could find online, nothing works though.
When I call `await channel.connect()` the program just hangs and doesn´t do anything

[image: image description]

Code Snippet:

```
@commands.command()
async def join(self, ctx):
    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel")
    else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
        await channel.connect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you didn't await `ctx.send`, second of all `discord.VoiceState` has no attribute `voice_channel`, it's `channel`.

Here's the fixed code:

```py
@commands.command()
async def join(self, ctx):
    if not ctx.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel")
    else:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()
```

[reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?%20voice#discord.VoiceState)

Comment: I tried your solution but it still didn't work. The bot has admin perms btw

Comment: do you have `intents.members` enabled?

Comment: yes, and i already kicked and reinvited the bot.

Comment: are you sure you have intents enabled?

Comment: Yup pretty sure, both in discord dev portal and in my code

Comment: did you import pynacl?

Comment: install pynacl `pip install PyNaCl` and in the code: `import nacl`

Comment: Wow that worked, just by importing. Can you explain why ? Was it specified in the docs?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need it, but it's a package you need when using voice support. If you don't import it there's the following error `PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice`

Comment: Also make sure to accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

According to [this docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.VoiceState)

I think you need to changes

`ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel` into `ctx.message.author.voice.channel`